# error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, iterator

Building queue implementation based on linked list. Cannot run application because of the two errors:

```
public class Queue<Integer> implements Iterable<Integer> {
    ...
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator()  {
            return new ListIterator(first);
        }
    private class ListIterator<Integer> implements Iterator<Integer> {// error #1
            private Node<Integer> current;

            public ListIterator(Node<Integer> first) {
                current = first;
            }

            public boolean hasNext(){ return current != null;                   }
            public void remove()    { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}

            public int next() { // error #2
                if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
                int item = current.item;
                current = current.next;
                return item;
            }
        }    
     }
```

**error #1:** error: Queue.ListIterator is not abstract and does not override abstract method next() in Iterator
where Integer is a type-variable:
Integer extends Object declared in class Queue.ListIterator

**error #2:** error: next() in Queue.ListIterator cannot implement next() in Iterator
return type int is not compatible with Integer
where E,Integer are type-variables:
E extends Object declared in interface Iterator
Integer extends Object declared in class Queue.ListIterator

How to get it working?

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: IntelliJ and those errors should tell you exactly what to do. Replace `int` with `Integer`.

Comment: Doesn't work because it fixes **error#2** and **error#1** but tells that **Incompatible types** for `return item;`

Comment: Nvm it's the generic type parameter declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boxing and unboxing in Java simplify code in many places, but method return types is not one of them.  The `next` method must return an `Integer`, not an `int`.  It must match the generic type parameter exactly.

```
public Integer next()
```

Second, you've declared a generic type parameter `Integer` in your `Queue` and `ListIterator` classes that has nothing to do with `java.lang.Integer`.  Remove it:

```
//              here
public class Queue implements Iterable<Integer> {
```

and

```
//                      here
private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I need to make this queue more universal: to process not only integers but all elements that can be iterated over? Do I have to specify `public class Queue<?> implements Iterable<?>`?

Comment: if u want to process all elements then do not provide any generic type.it will give you a suppress warning but should work,then you can use autobxing to add any type of data you want, ints and strings..

Comment: @RCola Then you should have `public class Queue<T> implements Iterable<T>`, and make use of the type param in your code (instead of Integer).